# Can you re-enter Peru on a travel visa?

Tags: tourist-visas, backpacking

Me and a friend are traveling in South America for 2 months, traveling from Lima, to Bolivia (La Paz) to Chile (San Pedro) then back into Peru via Tachna to fly out from Lima on the 18th of July. We both have UK (english) passports and are getting concerned that we may not be able to re-enter Peru. We cannot find anything online that can help, does anyone know specifically about the legislation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [British nationals](http://www.consulado.pe/es/londres/tramite/Paginas/Issuance-of-Tourist-Visa.aspx), among others, you do not require a visa to travel to Peru as tourists, part of your South American trip. You may have had your passports stamped when you initially entered, but that entry was visa-free. Those who do require one are often given a single-entry visa, and that may be your concern, but it doesn't apply to you. You'll re-enter the country and, shortly after, take your departure flight from Lima.